# I can't install any module by pip/ VScode can't found any module which I've just download

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, modulenotfounderror

I've tried so many ways to fix this problem, like I've uninstall every python version I've downloaded and reinstall python 3.10.1(Although it show me that it was 3.9.10 when I check it by windows 11 cmd but VScode show me that it was 3.10.1. I have no idea that which I should trust). And I've also tried to install the module again and again(It said I've already install it). Also I can see the module was in my computer, which mean I can see it in the file. What's wrong??? If you know what's happened and you know how to fix it, please tell me! I need your suggestion to fix this stupid problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple python environments and which environment you have installed the python modules was not which you have selected in the VSCode.

In the cmd execute `where python` to check all the python environments you have installed. In the VSCode click the python interpreter at the bottom-left on the VSCode to switch the python interpreter.